# Is it possible to import Java models on Objective c?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, json

I have some Java model on the server but in my iOS app I'm using JSON without a serializator because my server hasn't an Objective-C model generator.

Is it possible to integrate Java model class in Objective-C?

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you definitely can but you will see you are much better off "translating".

These are the step by step instructions (source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040321163154226).

1. Create a new Foundation project called "HelloBridge"
2. Create a new Pure Java Package target called "JavaClasses"
3. Create a new Java class called "HelloBridge.java" an add it to target
   "JavaClasses":

   ```
   public class HelloBridge {
      private String string = "Hello";

      public void setString(String string) {
         this.string = string;
      }

      public String getString() {
         return this.string;
      }

      public void printString() {
         System.out.println(this.string);
      }
   }
   ```
4. Add "HelloBridge.java" to the "Sources" build phase in target
   "JavaClasses"
5. Create a new empty file called "JavaInterfaces.h" and add it to
   target "HelloBridge":

   ```
   // Provide Objective-C interfaces for the Java classes
   // Not only good practice, it provides Code Sense
   @interface java_util_Vector : NSObject
   {}
   - (void)add:(id)anObject;
   - (id)get:(int)index;
   @end

   @interface HelloBridge : NSObject
   {}
   - (void)setString:(NSString *)string;
   - (NSString *)getString;
   - (void)printString;
   @end
   ```
6. Modify "main.m":

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import "JavaInterfaces.h"

   int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
      NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

      // Load the Java VM
      id vm = NSJavaSetupVirtualMachine();

      // Start the Java class loader
      NSJavaClassesFromPath(nil, nil, YES, &vm);

      // Load a new instance of the java.util.Vector Java class into an Objective-C pointer
      java_util_Vector * vector = NSJavaObjectNamedInPath(@"java.util.Vector", nil);
      [vector add:@"one item!"];
      NSLog(@"item 1=%@",[vector get:0]);
      [vector release];

      // Load a new instance of our custom HelloBridge Java class into an Objective-C pointer
      HelloBridge * hello = NSJavaObjectNamedInPath(@"HelloBridge", nil);
      NSLog(@"item 1=%@",[hello getString]);
      [hello setString:@"Test"];
      NSLog(@"item 1=%@",[hello getString]);
      [hello printString];
      [hello release];

      [pool release];
      return 0;
   }
   ```
7. Select "JavaClasses" from the targets drop box and Build it
8. Select "HelloBridge" from the targets drop box and Build/Run it

Comment: woha, it's kinda complicated. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I told you that it was better to translate into NSObjects :)